# British Olympiad; Combinatorics Recursion

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Isaac is planning a nine-day holiday. Every day he will go surfing,
>   or water skiing, or he will rest. On any given day he does just one of
>   these three things. He never does different water-sports on consecutive
>   days. How many schedules are possible for the holiday?

$A$ is surfing, $B$ is water-skiing and $C$ is resting.

Three cases, case 1, week begins with $A$, case 2, week begins with $B$ and case 3, week begins with $C$. Then the total possible weeks by $x(n)$ is:

$$x(n) = a(n) + b(n) + c(n)$$

Where $a(n)$ is the sequence with beginning $A$ etc...

Lets look at case 1 first.

Because it is $A$ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _,

$$a(n) = c(n-1) + a(n-1)$$

But I cant get rid of $a$, which is the goal. What should I do?

Comment: How did you expect to "get rid of $a$"? In this kind of (attempt of) solution, one only expects to get a recursion that goes back to a known initial state (which we have: $a(1)=1$ ) . The issue here is to solve this coupled equations.

Comment: @Nathanson That's not right -- he can do multiple $A$'s in a row or multiple $B$'s in a row.

Comment: @Lebes Look at all three cases before you give up.  You can't eliminate $a$ based on only one case -- you need them all together.

Comment: @Tad I see. I read it as not doing watersports in consecutive days.

Comment: I think that there is a solution here (if it's correct I did not verify it):http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2962h1051429

Answer (score 1):

Denote $s_n$ the number of possibilities spanning $n$ days, the first one being surfing. In the same way, denote $w_n,r_n$ the possibilities when the first day is water ski or rest, respectively. You have the following recurrence relations
$$ \begin{cases}  s_n = w_{n-1}+r_{n-1} \\ w_n = s_{n-1}+r_{n-1} \\ r_n = s_{n-1}+w_{n-1}+r_{n-1} \end{cases} $$

The easy way out is to write this as a matrix multiplication $Av_{n-1}=v_n$, where $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1& 0 & 1\\ 1& 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}, v_n = \begin{pmatrix} s_n \\ w_n \\ r_n \end{pmatrix}$. Start with $s_1=w_1=r_1=1$. We have $v_9 = A^8 \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 985\\ 985\\ 1393\end{pmatrix}$, giving a total of $3363$ possibilities.

Since this is an olympiad problem, it must have a simpler solution. Denote $a_n = s_n+w_n+r_n$. Then the recurrence relations imply that
$$ a_n = 2s_{n-1}+2w_{n-1}+3r_{n-1}=2a_{n-1}+r_{n-1}=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}.$$ 
Now this is a simple linear recurrence with $a_1 = 3,a_2 = 7$. In a few steps you get $a_9 = 3363$.