# Number of distinct paths in directed graph visiting all vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, directed-graphs

The following child's homework problem states:

> Jo is going on an 8-day activity holiday. Each day she can choose one of the water sports: kayaking or sailing, or land-based sports. She never does different water sports on consecutive days. She also wants to try all three options on at least one day of her holiday.
> How many different schedules are possible?

This is effectively "How many distinct walks of length 7 visiting each node at least once are there on the following directed graph?":

[image]

Or alternatively, "How many sequences of length 8 on the alphabet $\{L,K,S\}$ exist not containing the subsequence $SK$, or $KS$, and which feature each letter at least once?".

How would one solve such a problem, without exhaustively enumerating all paths?

---

- Note: If the 'must visit all vertices' condition were removed it would just be $|A^7|$, the sum of the entries of the 7th power of the adjacency matrix of the graph: [British Olympiad; Combinatorics Recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213249/british-olympiad-combinatorics-recursion)
- Note: this is **not** the number of Hamiltonian paths since vertices can (and at least one must) be visited more than once.

Answer (score 3):

If we temporarily forget about the condition that requires Jo to try all three options once, then this is indeed the number of walks of length **seven** (not eight!) in the directed graph, which can be counted by summing the entries of
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^7 = \begin{bmatrix}
 120 & 169 & 119 \\
 169 & 239 & 169 \\
 119 & 169 & 120 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
(It's a bit faster to compute this  if instead we sum the middle row of $A^8 = ((A^2)^2)^2$.)

Then, it is easiest to eliminate the cases we don't like by inclusion-exclusion:

- Subtract the $2^8$ walks which only visit Land or Kayak;
- Subtract the $2^8$ walks which only visit Land or Sail;
- Add back the $1$ walk which only visits Land.

This gives us $1393 - 2 \cdot 256 + 1 = 882$ as the final answer.

Comment: As a general solution strategy I'd say though that this approach falls flat - in the end, isn't this inclusion-exclusion for all induced subgraphs (via subsets of nodes), and therefore, in general something that has $O(2^n)$ summands?

Comment: Yes, but if you find an approach with $\operatorname{poly}(n)$ summands, you'll have a proof that P=NP, so...

Comment: I'm actually not so sure about that - given that our $n$ is in this case a natural number, even a method with $O(n)$ would only be pseudo polynomial, analogous to the knapsack problem.

Comment: @Sudix I was assuming you were taking $n$ to be the number of vertices. The number of summands does not grow with the length of the walk at all.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I confused myself there as in my head both were $n$.

Comment: Do you know where I could find a proof showing the #P/NP-completeness of the problem?

Comment: My argument is simply that by checking if there are any such walks of length $n-1$ in an $n$-vertex graph, we check if there is a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: That's a nice one!